# what is the difference between callback function as an parameter and callback keyword as an parameter?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am confused in the following  two code:

**1.**

`MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } }, { oldEnough: true }, callback);`

**2.**

```
MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } },{ oldEnough: true }, function
          (err,numberAff, raw){
              if (err) return handleError(err);
       });
```

in first code `callback` is passing as an parameter and in 2nd callback function is using as an parameter.what the `callback` represent in first code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code `callback` is the name of a function defined elsewhere.

The second code is about the same as

```
   function callback(err,numberAff, raw){
          if (err) return handleError(err);
   }

   MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } },{ oldEnough: true }, callback);
```